# Посоветуйте скрипт, работающий с doc файлами

Tags: ms-word, php

Нашёл нормальный скрипт PHPWord, настроил его, запустил - всё работает. Это мне надо, чтобы по шаблону заменял маркеры на введёные пользователем поля. Но проблема в том, что он сохраняет в docx(т.е. Word 2007), а нужно, чтобы у всех пошло, поэтому нужно doc(т.е. Word 97-2003). Посоветуйте скрипт, который сохранял бы в doc, или может где-то алгоритм сохранения в doc написан, чтобы я переписал скрипт PHPWord.

Comment: измени тупо расширение :)

Comment: не поможет. doc и docx - это два разных формата.
@mctrane используй rtf и будет счастье!

Comment: Блин, вот именно что phpword просто меняет расширение, когда нужно совсем в другой формат сохранять и в результате чего в 2003 данный формат не читается. Ну а с RTF как работать, есть ли там возможность сохранять картинки, таблицы?